# Remove newlines (\n) but exclude lines with specific regex?

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk

After a lot of searching, I've come across a few ways to remove newlines using sed or tr

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g'

tr -d '\n'
```

However, I can't find a way to exclude the action from specific lines.  I've learned that one can use the "!" in sed as a means to exclude an address from a subsequent action, but I can't figure out how to incorporate it into the sed command above.  Here's an example of what I'm trying to resolve.

I have a file formatted as such:

```
>sequence_ID_1
atcgatcgggatc
aatgacttcattg
gagaccgaga
>sequence_ID_2
gatccatggacgt
ttaacgcgatgac
atactaggatcag
at
```

I want the file formatted in this fashion:

```
>sequence_ID_1
atcgatcgggatcaatgacttcattggagaccgaga
>sequence_ID_2
gatccatggacgtttaacgcgatgacatactaggatcagat
```

I've been focusing on trying to exclude lines containing the ">" character, as this is the only constant regex that would exist on lines that have the ">" character (note: the sequence_ID_n is unique to each entry preceded by the ">" and, thus, cannot be relied upon for regex matching).

I've attempted this:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;/^>/!s/\n//g' file.txt > file2.txt
```

It runs without generating an error, but the output file is the same as the original.

Maybe I can't do this with sed?  Maybe I'm approaching this problem incorrectly?  Should I be trying to define a range of lines to operate on (i.e. only lines between lines beginning with ">")?

I'm brand new to basic text manipulation, so any suggestions are greatly, greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `awk` should work:

```
$ awk '/^>/{print (NR==1)?$0:"\n"$0;next}{printf "%s", $0}END{print ""}' file
>sequence_ID_1
atcgatcgggatcaatgacttcattggagaccgaga
>sequence_ID_2
gatccatggacgtttaacgcgatgacatactaggatcagat
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response and solution!  I'm going to dive deeper into the copy of the O'Reilly sed & awk book I have to come to a complete understanding of how/what's happening here.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;N;/^>/M!s/\n//;ta;P;D' file
```

Remove newlines from lines that don't begin with a `>`.

Comment: +1, because it uses `sed` and it works, but my brain is still hurting from trying to understand.

Comment: Thanks for the sed solution!  This looks crazy and I'm excited to tease apart how it works!

Answer (score 1):

As @1_CR already said @jaypal's solution is a good way to do it. But I really could not resist to try it in pure Bash. See the comments for details:

The input data:

```
$ cat input.txt
>sequence_ID_1
atcgatcgggatc
aatgacttcattg
gagaccgaga
>sequence_ID_2
gatccatggacgt
ttaacgcgatgac
atactaggatcag
at
>sequence_ID_20
gattaca
```

The script:

```
$ cat script
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Bash 4 - read the data line by line into an array
readarray -t data < "$1"

# Bash 3 - read the data line by line into an array
#while read line; do
#    data+=("$line")
#done < "$1"

# A search pattern
pattern="^>sequence_ID_[0-9]"

# An array to insert the revised data
merged=()

# A counter
counter=0

# Iterate over each item in our data array
for item in "${data[@]}"; do

    # If an item matches the pattern
    if [[ "$item" =~ $pattern ]]; then

        # Add the item straight into our new array
        merged+=("$item")

        # Raise the counter in order to write the next
        # possible non-matching item to a new index
        (( counter++ ))

        # Continue the loop from the beginning - skip the
        # rest of the code inside the loop for now since it 
        # is not relevant after we have found a match.
        continue
    fi

    # If we have a match in our merged array then
    # raise the counter one more time in order to
    # get a new index position
    [[ "${merged[$counter]}" =~ $pattern ]] && (( counter++ ))

    # Add a non matching value to the already existing index
    # currently having the highest index value based on the counter
    merged[$counter]+="$item"
done

# Test: Echo each item of our merged array
printf "%s\n" "${merged[@]}"
```

The result:

```
$ ./script input.txt

>sequence_ID_1
atcgatcgggatcaatgacttcattggagaccgaga
>sequence_ID_2
gatccatggacgtttaacgcgatgacatactaggatcagat
>sequence_ID_20
gattaca
```

Comment: Thanks for this alternative and particularly for the line comments!  Extremely useful for understanding how it all works!

Comment: You are welcome. I refined the comments a little bit and added an alternative way to read the lines into an array with Bash 3.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU sed:

```
sed -r ':a;/^[^>]/{$!N;s/\n([^>])/\1/;ta}' inputfile
```

For your input, it'd produce:

```
>sequence_ID_1
atcgatcgggatcatgacttcattgagaccgaga
>sequence_ID_2
gatccatggacgttaacgcgatgactactaggatcagt
```

Comment: Great (and mind-bending), but you're dropping the first non-`>` char. in your substitution; also, it seems that the `P;D` is not necessary; thus: `sed -r ':a;/^[^>]/{$!N;s/\n([^>])/\1/;ta}' inputfile`

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks.  I was, indeed, dropping the first character.

Comment: With some `-e` acrobatics you can also make this work with BSD (OSX) sed: `sed -E -e ':a' -e '/^[^>]/{$!N;s/\n([^>])/\1/; ta' -e '}' inputfile`.

Comment: Thanks @mklement0 for the OSX info.  Most of my lab mates use OSX, so this will come in handy for them!

Answer (score 0):

Jaypal's solution is the way to go, here's a GNU awk variant

```
awk -v RS='>sequence[^\\n]+\\n' 
'{gsub("\n", "");printf "%s%s%s", $0, NR==1?"":"\n", RT}'  file
>sequence_ID_1
atcgatcgggatcaatgacttcattggagaccgaga
>sequence_ID_2
gatccatggacgtttaacgcgatgacatactaggatcagat
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it with `awk`

```
awk '{printf (/^>/&&NR>1?RS:"")"%s"(/^>/?RS:""),$0}' file
>sequence_ID_1
atcgatcgggatcaatgacttcattggagaccgaga
>sequence_ID_2
gatccatggacgtttaacgcgatgacatactaggatcagat
```